# Encountering error running the test for regos saying "rego_unsafe_var_error"

Tags: .net, unit-testing, open-policy-agent, rego

Getting error while running test for my rego files.
Rego file :

```
package authz
import abc.def

default can_tigger = false

can_tigger = true{
    needs_one_of := ["trigger_access_allowed"]
    access.allowed_for_triger(input.appId, input.user, needs_one_of[_],input.resource)
}
```

Rego test file :

```
package authz

test_can_trigger_command_when_projectId_is_valid {
    can_tigger
    with input as {"projectId": "5fdf4ab1-acf6-4d5f-9604-79bda49d9431", "user": {"sub": "testUser"}}    
}
```

If I set the value in test file for `can_tigger:= true/false` then my test would pass, but doing is not a proper way to write tests.

Comment: Looks like you are using both `input.appId` and `input.resource` in your `allowed_for_triger` call, yet none of them are included when you mock the input using `with`

Answer (score 1):

The [OPA Gatekeeper Library](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library) is a great way to learn how to write tests for Rego.

From the [k8sallowedrepos test](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/blob/master/src/general/allowedrepos/src_test.rego):

```
test_input_allowed_container {
    input := { "review": input_review(input_container_allowed), "parameters": {"repos": ["allowed"]}}
    results := violation with input as input
    count(results) == 0
}
...
input_init_review(containers) = output {
    output = {
      "object": {
        "metadata": {
            "name": "nginx"
        },
        "spec": {
            "initContainers": containers,
        }
      }
     }
}

input_container_allowed = [
{
    "name": "nginx",
    "image": "allowed/nginx",
}]
```

Note that in the test, `violation with input as input` is a Rego idiom that passes the local "input" variable to the [violation defined here](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/blob/master/src/general/allowedrepos/src.rego) using as "input". It's much cleaner than doing it inline.

In your case, you could rewrite your test as:

```
test_can_trigger_command_when_projectId_is_valid {
    input := {"projectId": "5fdf4ab1-acf6-4d5f-9604-79bda49d9431", "user": {"sub": "testUser"}}
    results := violation with input as input
    count(results) == 0
}
```